# Select multiple element types in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select `td` and `th` of a `table`. At the moment I only can select `td` *or* `th`. How can I make this shorter?

```
$table.find('tr th:nth-child(' + colIndex + ')').css('color', 'red');
$table.find('tr td:nth-child(' + colIndex + ')').css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: have you find answer? if yes then please select as answer or explain some more..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the TDs contain data you need to not drill too deep, so use an immediate child selector before `:nth-child`:

```
$table.find('tr > :nth-child(' + colIndex + ')').css('color', 'red');
```

**JSFiddle (based on @Rory McCrossan's):** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/o8wwf1ze/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```js
var colIndex = 2;
var $table = $('table')
$table.find('tr').find(
        'th:nth-child('+colIndex+'),'+
        'td:nth-child('+colIndex+')')
    .css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```